# How to create a report for individual subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, email-studio

Is there any way to create a report that relates to email send, open and click data at an individual level in marketing cloud?
I tried using query activity in a DE but I was getting empty results.

```
SELECT j.EmailName, s.EmailAddress,s.SubscriberID,op.EventDate as OpenDate from  _Job j 
JOIN _Sent se on j.JobID = se.JobID
JOIN _Open op on j.JobID = op.JobID
JOIN _Subscribers s ON se.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
```

Comment: If you just want to know these details for a single customer then you can find either in ALL SUBSCRIBER as here https://pasteboard.co/IR9ysca.png ... or from CONTACT BUILDER as here https://pasteboard.co/IR9yVu8.png

Comment: yeah but I want a report where I can see the details in a single place rather than going to each user and checking it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this query from a child business unit? If so, the *_Subscribers* data view could be causing issues. Try changing it to 'ent._Subscribers' in the JOIN. The *_Subscribers* data view in child business units will either be empty or only contain a few records, meaning an inner join may result in losing the full data set.

Likewise, if you are running the query from a Parent business unit and hoping to get data across multiple business units, the *_Job* data view will only pull job data from the business unit the query is run from - so that may also be the issue.

Extra note, you'll likely gain more value pulling in Subscriber Key than Subscriber ID in the SELECT statement (Subscriber ID is scarcely viewable throughout SFMC), where Subscriber ID more efficient to use in the JOIN due to system indexes.

Comment: When I'm using ent.Subscribers I'm getting this error - ent._Subscribers is not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query existing data extensions or system data views.  I will try running this in the Parent BU and will inform you.

Comment: Do we require to enable something or contact support to query this in the child BU?